# HTML <select> <option> with too many options gets slow

Tags: javascript, html, performance

What is the best solution to make `<select>` `<option>` with 4000 items faster

Comment: I'd suggest a moving to typeahead if you want 4000+ options, you can then return results that match the user input. If you still want to pre-populate it, populate them with most frequent options. should make it much better than having that many options.

Comment: The problem is I populate value/display text text like <option value="1">New York</option>

Comment: also your solution is very good, I will try typeahead with other hidden input in the form to hold the value